# Is there a way to call a Cloud Function through Cloud Task using form-data?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, cloud, task

I have a Cloud Function(Python - Flask) that is expecting to receive a form-data with two files, it works well when I request it directly, but using Cloud Task it's not reaching in there. Here is what I get: `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

ps: Using Python for the Cloud Function and Node.JS for the Cloud Task.

Tried to Google, and searched over here and have no answers, even the docs don't say anything about it. Any tips?

that's the code that I'm using to call Cloud Task:

```js
const auth = new GoogleAuth({})
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ credentials: credentials });

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf_file', 'x');

const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    url,
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: "x@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  }
}

const request = { parent: parent, task: task, auth: auth }
const [ response ] = await client.createTask(request);
console.log(response);
console.log(`created task ${response.name}`);
```

that's the code for my Cloud Function, that I'm using as a test:

```py
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def main(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        print('ERROR: its not a post request')
        return {'error': 'Invalid method'}, 400

    print(request.form)

    return 'ok'
```

Comment: Did you try without form data? or with another service account?

Comment: hello @guillaumeblaquiere I've been through these days trying to send the form-data but had not success, updated the OP with the cloud function that I'm using as a test. I'm thinking that Cloud Tasks doesn't support form-data :/